# WebRTC: Firefox Enable IPv6

Tags: javascript, html, webrtc

I am playing around with WebRTC. I want to create a connection using IPv6 for Chrome there is the `googIPv6` constraint which works out of the box:

```
{
    'mandatory': {
                    'googIPv6': true
                 }
}
```

Is there any way I can use IPv6 in Firefox as well?

Comment: Not yet apparently https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=797262

Answer (score 0):

Firefox WebRTC supports IPv6 since version 42. There are no constraints supported to turn IPv6 support for WebRTC in Firefox on or off. IPv6 support is on by default since version 42.

IPv6 support landed in version 42 in this ticket: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=797262

Comment: This is not a question. I am just answering Eun's question, which has not been answered yet.